# Are 307 Temporary Redirects safe for temporary new web site tests?

Tags: seo, google, php, redirects, a-b-testing

Our current site is getting close to being replaced. I was looking to do a test of our new sales funnel on the new site and compare the traffic and conversion ratios for a few days. So I was planning on doing 307 Temporary Redirects from the old site to the new site for a few days and see how the traffic reacts before a hard launch. I've seen some topics online of people doing something similar and being penalized by google can someone tell me if this is a safe way to approach this task? If not are their any alternative ways you would recommend.

We are going from a manually coded 2006 website to a new wordpress site all php/MYSQL.

Any insights or recommendations welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Searching around I'm going to give 302 redirect a try. Seems to be better supported and not have a penalty attached.